# How do I dispatch a Laravel job when app is deployed?

Tags: php, laravel

How do I dispatch a job during the deployment of my Laravel app?

Not sure if this matters, but the job I have built has an infinite loop that watches for particular changes to happen on S3. I know `AppServiceProvider` has a `boot()` method that I can dispatch jobs within, but this seems to run whenever a client loads my app, which is not the behavior I am looking for, as I only need this job to be dispatched once.

Comment: By deployed you mean after copying some files to your server?

Comment: How is your deployment done? Most automated deployment tools have some sort of hook to run scripts at certain points.

Comment: I'm using OpsWorks for deployment. I suppose I could create a Laravel console command that dispatches my job and run it automatically post-deploy. Would this be an appropriate approach?

Comment: @BenInada That's absolutely fine. I would do just that myself.